# Creating a single layer of polygons from a point layer

Tags: qgis, csv, polygon-creation

I have a csv file of lats and lons for points that represent the vertices of parcels of land. I want to create a polygon for each set of specific points within the csv and then create one unified layer of polygons.

I first started separating each set of points in the csv file and created individual point shp files and then used the points2one tool to create the polygons. This works but is unwieldy as I have now approximately 170 individual shp files. And I need to merge the newly created polygons back into one layer (seems a lot of unnecessary work).

My question is is it possible to import the entire csv points file into QGIS, manually select sets of points using the selection tool, and then create a polygon from that selection?

My parcels of land are not contiguous so I'm not sure how to create a single layer from the data.

Comment: If you already have the polygon shapefiles, you could use the Merge Layers Tool in the MMQGIS extension (http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) to merge them together.

Comment: I'm not directly familiar with the plugin, but I found indication that as of the latest version from a month or so ago it included some option for a sort field. I assume there must be some attribute in your csv that identifies which points go with which parcels? Using that field might do what you want. Most operations like this are similar - you need some attribute to group the points and the tool has to be able to use it. Sometimes it's two steps, first to lines then polygons.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes there is a sort vertices option in the plugin which will definitely help. I've managed to do what I need with lots of donkey work. I think its time to look at the python console. Thanks for your answer.